# How do I use ® in meta description

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo

I've got a client who wants their meta descriptions to include the register symbol, but it gives me an invalid character error, and using `&reg;` doesn't translate to a ® in the description. Using ree-1.8.7 and rails 3.1.1

Some additional information, this page description is saved in a controller as `@page_description` and then brought in on the page in a partial. The error seems to be occurring in the controller, so I'm guessing there must be a ruby way of using the ® symbol.

Comment: Have you tried putting the actual character into the source, and specifying the file encoding as UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, UTF-8 is specified and I used the utf ® symbol to create the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `html_safe` method to render the string as html.

try `@page_description.html_safe`

---

Edit 1:

`&reg;` is the character entity reference for `®` in html.

Rails does not render string as html by default.

In order to override this behaviour, you need to use `html_safe` to render the string as html.

Comment: This worked, but only after I realized that you need to use `&reg;` in the string for this to work. If you'll specify that so others will know in the future, I'll check this the answer.